# Parameterize JMeter HTTP request path

Tags: java, gradle, jmeter

I'm creating JMeter tests for a service which context root may change depending on the host/environment. I'm trying to map the context root within the HTTP request path as follows:

[Http request path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45FDi.png)

I've created a user defined variable as follows:

[contextRoot user variable definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJPSY.png)

I'm running my tests using [jmeter-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin) and that's how I'm passing the context root as a command line parameter:

```
-PcontextRoot=/my-context-root
```

But I'm always getting 404 responses because JMeter is not replacing the variable with the parameter value as expected.

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [Advanced Usage](https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin/wiki/Advanced-Usage) section JMeter Gradle Plugin seems to be supporting "normal" [JMeter command-line arguments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options), therefore you should use `-J` argument instead of `-P`

> J, --jmeterproperty {argument}={value}, Define additional JMeter properties

So substitute your `-PcontextRoot=/my-context-root` with `-JcontextRoot=/my-context-root`

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

You can also omit this User Defined Variables and put your [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) directly to the HTTP Request sampler path (or even better go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Your suggestion about replacing -P with -J didn't work initially because gradle doesn't know the -J flag. But I got your idea and I've changed my build.gradle file to add the contextRoot parameter to the JMeter param list, in a way that I can now pass the property via -P flag:

`jmUserProperties = [
    "contextRoot=" + System.getProperty("contextRoot", "")
]`

On your second suggestion about omitting the user defined variables, I did it and it's working fine. Thanks.